# Define a condition in cloudformation template with alarms

Tags: conditional-statements, aws-cloudformation, alarm

How to define/declare a condition to create an alarm in prod?
With the condition:Isprod would work to create an alarm in prod?

WOULD this work? how to define a condition below?

```
LambdaInvocationsAlarm:
Condition: IsProd
Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
Properties:
  AlarmDescription: Lambda invocations
  AlarmName: LambdaInvocationsAlarm
  ComparisonOperator: LessThanLowerOrGreaterThanUpperThreshold
  EvaluationPeriods: 1
  Metrics:
  - Expression: ANOMALY_DETECTION_BAND(m1, 2)
    Id: ad1
  - Id: m1
    MetricStat:
      Metric:
        MetricName: Invocations
        Namespace: AWS/Lambda
      Period: !!int 86400
      Stat: Sum
  ThresholdMetricId: ad1
  TreatMissingData: breaching
```

Comment: You have to provide full template and explain why it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As @Marcin said, you should explain what you have tried and what is blocking more precisely.

But what you suggest could work yes: you can define a `Condition` named `isProd` and use it to create - or not - resources. Regarding this condition: AWS does not know what is a production stage in your environment, so you need to specify that. Does your production stage matches an account? Does it match a region? Something else?

As an example and if we assume that your production stage matches a specific AWS account, then you could define the condition as below (it's JSON, feel free to convert to YAML):

```
{
  "Parameters": {
    "ProdAccountParameter": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "Enter the production account identifier."
    }
  },
  "Conditions": {
    "isProd": {
      "Fn::Equals": [
        {
          "Ref": "ProdAccountParameter"
        },
        {
          "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

*(Then, when deploying the template, you'll need to provide your AWS production account).*

Comment: Great. Just curious: how do you differentiate prod from beta if you don't use account or region as criteria?